# How to make a request sync wait for another request of the same NodeJS/express webservice?

Tags: node.js, express, request, wait, synchronous

I have simplified my code and I'm looking for a method to wait properly for an internal var to increase (like a mutex).

Request #1:`/call` is called first from a browser and must wait, request #2:`/trigger` is called from another browser for example, and then request #1 must return its result.

Here is my example code, quite simple but the part "TODO" is very difficult. I've already tried with a while-loop but it block the entire process and do not accept the request #2 (I think it can be done with promises or with async/await, but I don't see how to use these)

```
[code was removed, cf. below]
```

Thanks for advance !

**EDIT:** Many thanks to you, [grappeq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8725480/grappeq) ! Here is my working code according to the publish & subscribe pattern, and updated so `/trigger` and `/call` can be launched whatever the order is :

```
var app = require('express')();
var token = 0;
require("http").createServer(app).listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Launched");
});
class Quartz {
    constructor() {
        this.callbacks = [];
    }
    retry() {
        throw "";
    }
    call(callback) {
        this.callbacks.push(callback);
        this.trigger();
    }
    trigger(...args) {
        var failedCallbacks = [];
        while (this.callbacks.length > 0) {
            var callback = this.callbacks.shift();
            try {
                callback(...args);
            } catch (e) {
                failedCallbacks.push(callback);
            }
        }
        this.callbacks = failedCallbacks;
    }
};
var quartz = new Quartz();
app.get('/call', (request, response) => {
    console.log("Wait");
    var start = Date.now();
    quartz.call(() => {
        if (token <= 0)
            quartz.retry();
        token--;
        response.status(200).json({
            "func": "/call",
            "value": token,
            "time": Date.now()-start
        });
    });
});
app.get('/trigger', (request, response) => {
    console.log("Trigger");
    var start = Date.now();
    token++;
    quartz.trigger();
    response.status(200).json({
        "func": "/trigger",
        "value": token,
        "time": Date.now()-start
    });
});
```

Comment: while loop blocked which process?

Comment: The full process, the entire webservice is stuck in an infinite loop and doesn't respond to `/call` nor `/trigger` anymore.

Comment: You could always use `setInterval` if while loop causes problem for you

Comment: it's a very simplified version of my webservice, `setInterval` alternative is not the properly BP against promises or async/await possible versions.

Comment: Hmm maybe I'm wrong, how would you do with a `setInterval` without looping and consuming ?

Comment: If you are waiting for `/trigger` api  to be processed before responding for `/call` api, you are designing it wrong. I think its better if you design a third api that returns your token value and you should call it from frontend to check token before calling `/call` api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest to use [publish/subscribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern e.g.:

```
var app = require('express')();
var token = 0;
require("http").createServer(app).listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Launched");
});

class PubSub {
    constructor() {
        this.callbacks = [];
    }

    sub(callback) {
        this.callbacks.push(callback);
    }

    pub(...args) {
        this.callbacks.forEach(callback => { callback(...args); });
    }
};

var pubsub = new PubSub();

app.get('/call', (request, response) => {
    console.log("Call");
    var start = Date.now();
    pubsub.sub(() => {
        response.status(200).json({
            "func": "/call",
            "value": token,
            "time": Date.now()-start
        });
    })
});
app.get('/trigger', (request, response) => {
    console.log("Trigger");
    var start = Date.now();
    pubsub.pub();
    response.status(200).json({
        "func": "/trigger",
        "value": token,
        "time": Date.now()-start
    });
});
```

Of course usage of a library like RxJs should be preferred for that over some random code I put together in several minutes.

BTW, consider using [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) instead.

Comment: That was exactly the kind of vanilla-ish and clean approch I was looking for, thanks a lot ! cf. above

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved using Events:

```js
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

var app = require('express')();

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Launched");
});

app.get('/call', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Call");

    var start = Date.now();

    eventEmitter.on('tokenEvent', (token) => {
        res.status(200).json({
            "func": "/call",
            "value": token,
            "time": Date.now() - start
        });
    });

});


app.get("/trigger", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Trigger");
    var start = Date.now();

    var token = 1;

    eventEmitter.emit('tokenEvent', token);

    res.status(200).json({
        "func": "/trigger",
        "value": token,
        "time": Date.now() - start
    });

});
```

Note, that you probably will need to secure lines:

```
eventEmitter.on('tokenEvent', (token) => {
        res.status(200).json({
```

because `/trigger` can be invoked before `/call` (`!res.headersSent` may be used)